# Adapt Flow Layout to a Qt Table

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I'm working on a project in which I'd like to make something like the pattern explorer in Photoshop (as in this picture http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/392001_393000/392193.png)`;

I originally was doing so using a custom QAbstractTableModel coupled with a QTableView but I have to set the numbers of rows and cols from the Model itself.
This is a problem because I want the columns to adapt to the viewer width as in the FlowLayout example : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-flowlayout.html

It seems that the model/view system isn't adapted to what I want to do, but I don't know how to make my widget look like a table (as in the screenshot above).

Could you help me on that point ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Use **QListView** with

```
setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
```